# Where can I find a list of timezones?

Tags: ios, nstimezone

I use timeZoneWithName, but I don't know names of timezones. Where can I find a list of timezones?

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"US/Eastern"];
```

Comment: This might have information on where to look: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

Comment: http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/xtra/tzdatepick.html

Comment: This is a programming related question, because the timezone names might be different depending on plateform, OS versions... Those who voted this question off topic just didn't bother to understand it correctly.

Comment: This should not be closed. In order to use this method correctly, you need to understand its valid inputs. It is a useful reference to any developer using, say, NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Hi @GregHewgill, how does one know that NSTimezone use the exact same list as the list on Wikipedia? Besides, isn't Apple known for doing things its own way?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I found solution.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]);
```

Comment: Since I can't post an answer, I've pasted this at pastebin.com.  This is the whole list as of the latest iOS 6 release: http://pastebin.com/ibNU2RcG

Comment: If you want need more dynamic timezone regarding the name of the city for example you can use, in Swift:

`let parisTimezoneName = NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames().filter {
                    $0.containsString("Paris")
                    }.first; dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: parisTimezoneName!)`

Comment: Or in Swift 4 just use print(TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary)